# How to create DropDown list with only the Arrow Down button in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, drop-down-menu

Hi I have an issue in AS3.

I want to create an arrow down button, which if I click it, it will give me other options and after clicking one of these options, it will trigger other events.

I was wondering if I can use the dropdown list to do so because the dropdown list has the bar thing before the arrow down, which I don't want to have that.

Thanks!

Comment: Which dropdown list? spark, mx, fl, flash?

Answer (score 0):

A simple spark button with an arrow?

Set an icon class (a simple little .png) for a spark button:

```
<s:Button width="50" height="50" icon="{Arrow}"/>
```

Where the class is simply something like this:

```
[Embed(source="Untitled-2.png")]
static private var Arrow:Class;
```

Comment: Thank you again BotMaster! I'm curious the best way to show my two "options" after clicking this arrow button, say option1 and option2. Would you suggest me to use a list or make two buttons or something so that it can show the two options similar to a dropdown list?

Comment: If it's always gonna be two options I would create a new mxml component extending Group and put two buttons in there (or anything else) then just show that custom group with those two components in there. Extending Group or related (HGroup, Panel, etc) is a very efficient and simple way to build your own static forms/form display.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will select your answer after I have enough reputation haha.